# Displaying Information from Multiple Shapefiles in Label Leaflet R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I am currently building a shinyapp with `leaflet` with multiple shapefile layers.
I would like the user to be able to hover over an area and see both the name of the census tract and zip code in the tooltip. This problem is made more difficult by the fact that zip codes and census tracts do not overlap neatly.
The solution may require some means of finding the intersections between the two shapefiles, though I am not sure on where to begin.

Is there any way for leaflet to recognize the position of the cursor across multiple polygon layers?

Reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)

zip_codes <- read_sf("shapefiles/ZCTA-Harris/ZCTA Harris.shp")
tracts <- read_sf("shapefiles/Tracts/Tracts 2020.shp")

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput(outputId = "map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet()%>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lat = 29.84, lng = -95.393462, zoom = 10)%>%
      addPolygons(
        data = zip_codes,
        weight = 2,
        opacity = 1,
        color = "black"
      )%>%
      addPolygons(
        data = tracts,
        weight = 2,
        opacity = 1,
        fillOpacity = 0,
        color = "firebrick",
        label = ~name
      )
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UadEC.jpg)

Comment: What about using two separate tooltips for each of your layers? or use the pop-up for one of the two? If this doesn't work for your purpose you have to bury your zip-codes in the census tracts. This could lead to another set of problems related to the overlapping issue that you described

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately the multiple tooltips doesn't work for leaflet because it will just default to whichever layer is on top and I need to see both simultaneously. Do you have any suggestions for burying the zip-codes in the census tracts?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240259/using-simple-features-sf-in-r-how-do-i-erase-polygons-overlapping-with-anothe). If you need more help you should provide a sample of your data